# Material Angular - Compile error - Class 'MatStepper' incorrectly extends base class 'CdkStepper'

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have problems with compiling my angular website. I have installed all necessary dependencies via npm, but it is not working. I use Material Angular too. And this is the problem, without it works.

Log:

```
webpack: Compiling...
Date: 2017-11-05T13:02:47.880Z
Hash: a4f6320620f5d2e9766f
Time: 665ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 5.79 kB [entry]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 1.85 MB [initial]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 551 kB [initial]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 150 kB [initial]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 12.8 MB [initial]


ERROR in C:/Users/Erik/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Erik\node_modules\@angular\core\@angular\core.es5.js'
 @ C:/Users/Erik/node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js 17:0-168
 @ ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/autocomplete.es5.js
 @ ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/material.es5.js
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts

webpack: Failed to compile.
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/stepper.d.ts(17,22): error TS2415: Class 'MatStepper' incorrectly extends base class 'CdkStepper'.
  Types of property '_steps' are incompatible.
    Type 'QueryList<MatStep>' is not assignable to type 'QueryList<CdkStep>'.
      Property '_dirty' is missing in type 'QueryList<MatStep>'.
../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/typings/focus-monitor.d.ts(10,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'.
../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/typings/list-key-manager.d.ts(9,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Subject'.
../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/collections/typings/collection-viewer.d.ts(8,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'.
../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/collections/typings/data-source.d.ts(8,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'.
../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/collections/typings/selection.d.ts(8,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Subject'.
../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/layout/typings/breakpoints-observer.d.ts(10,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'.
../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/typings/overlay-ref.d.ts(12,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'.
../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/typings/overlay-ref.d.ts(13,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Subject'.
../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/typings/position/connected-position-strategy.d.ts(12,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Subject'.
../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/typings/position/connected-position-strategy.d.ts(13,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'.
../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/typings/scroll-dispatcher.d.ts(10,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Subscription'.
../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/typings/scroll-dispatcher.d.ts(11,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'.
../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/typings/scrollable.d.ts(9,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'.
../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/typings/viewport-ruler.d.ts(10,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'.
../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/stepper/typings/stepper.d.ts(10,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms'.
../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/table/typings/table.d.ts(11,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'.
../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(8,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'.
../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/event_emitter.d.ts(8,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Subject'.
../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/query_list.d.ts(8,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'.
../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/util/lang.d.ts(8,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'.
```

Can you help me ? Have I installed bad dependencies or I forget something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One main reason for this error is your `angular material` package is at version 6+ whereas all other libraries are at 5+ version.

Therefore, in your `package.json` file,

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^6.0.1"    
  },
```

**change these to whatever the current version of the other angular components** just as follows.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.0"    
  },
```

After making these changes, open your command prompt and give

```
npm install
```

which will install all the libraries mentioned in your package.json in their specified versions. Following this, start your server which should successfully open your application in the web browser:

```
ng serve
```

Also, make sure you have added `BrowserAnimationsModule` in your app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatSnackBarModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 3):

It helped me:

```
npm uninstall --save @angular/material
npm install --save @angular/material@5.2.4
npm uninstall --save @angular/cdk
npm install --save @angular/cdk@5.2.4
```

I'm using Angular 5.