# node_modules and Angular issues

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material, node-modules

I cannot piece the reason for my errors:

> PS C:\Users\Zakariah Siyaji\Desktop\AngularAdmin> ng serve
>   ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost: 4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
>
> Date: 2018-08-18T23:32:59.066Z Hash: 8230d7de0b0765e109df Time: 9191ms
>   chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.06 kB [initial] [rendered]
>   chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 691 bytes
>   [initial] [rendered] chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map
>   (runtime) 5.4 kB [entry] [rendered] chunk {styles} styles.js,
>   styles.js.map (styles) 28.3 kB [initial] [rendered] chunk {vendor}
>   vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 325 kB [initial] [rendered]
>
> ERROR in
>   node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/stepper.d.ts(26,22):
>   error TS2415: Class 'MatStepper' incorrectly extends base class
>   'CdkStepper'.   Types of property '_stepHeader' are incompatible.
>       Type 'QueryList' is not assignable to type 'QueryList'.
>         Type 'ElementRef' is not assignable to type 'FocusableOption'.
>           Property 'focus' is missing in type 'ElementRef'.
>
> i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
>
> I deleted node_modules, I did npm install and npm update but neither
>   of those options fixed the issue. The code is flawless, it is simply
>   an issue related to node_modules and different packages.

Comment: Did you try npm cache clean --force

Comment: Yes I did, no luck

Comment: give us more info, you could start with `ng --version`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52505379/6550949 its been already answered in the above link